# Rotating around 2 points at the same time

Tags: c++, rotation, sfml

Basically, I'm trying to rotate a square around 2 points at the same time.

Here, when mouse is going left or right I'm trying to rotate the square around it's center, and when mouse is going up or down, I'm rotating around any other point (50:100 here). However, my square is jumping around the screen, and when I'm trying to rotate around the center only, it continues to rotate around 50:100.
Any suggestions how to fix that?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;

   Event evt;

    int main(int argc, char* argv)
    {
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(600, 600), "test");

RectangleShape test(Vector2<float>(20.0f, 20.0f));
test.setFillColor(Color::Red);
test.setPosition(300, 300);
test.setOrigin(10, 10);


Clock deltaTime;
Clock timer;
timer.restart();

int mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
int curMouseX = 0, curMouseY = 0;
float offset = 100;
bool moving = false;

while (window.isOpen())
{
    while (window.pollEvent(evt)) {
        switch (evt.type)
        {
        case Event::MouseMoved:
            curMouseX = mouseX;
            curMouseY = mouseY;
            mouseX = evt.mouseMove.x;
            mouseY = evt.mouseMove.y;
            moving = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    float elaspedTime = deltaTime.restart().asSeconds();

    if (curMouseX != mouseX && moving) {

        test.setOrigin(10, 10);
        test.rotate(360 * elaspedTime);
        //  test.setOrigin(50, 100); Tried this to avoid jumping. When uncommented, doesn't rotate around the center.
    }

    if (curMouseY != mouseY && moving) {
        test.setOrigin(50, 100);
        test.rotate(60 * elaspedTime);
    }
    window.clear();
    window.draw(test);
    window.display();
    moving = false;
}

return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Do you want your retangle to move continuously or only when the mouse moves?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `sf::Transfomable` class inherited from your shape, create a [`sf::Transform`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0-fr/classsf_1_1Transform.php) for it and use [`rotate (float angle, const Vector2f &center)`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0-fr/classsf_1_1Transform.php#ad2a2520ad81724079d109d4a986f9902)

You just have to store your mouse position each time it moves in a `sf::Vector2f`